# Is there a way to keep a SwiftRealm from creating object definitions that aren’t going to be used?

Tags: realm

**Perhaps I'm overthinking this**, so I'm looking for a reality check.  I have an app which uses a half dozen objects that it archives and works with.  I instantiate a Realm for each one of these six or so objects. Originally, my intent was to avoid having to migrate a Realm because of an object being updated which was not in any way related to the object I was using... But I noticed that each of my "dedicated" Realms can see all of the Realm objects in the entire app.

Why is this the desired behavior? I'm simply curious, and need to be motivated to untangle the mess I've created. Why is what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for any/all feedback you can provide.

Comment: I'm sincere in asking the question. In addition to down voting me, I'd appreciate if you could also tell me why so I can adjust the question to suit the forum.  Thanks.

Comment: Because you are using the default behavior instead of using class subsets and specifying the object types that the Realm should use as its schema: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#class-subsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the schema of a Realm configuration using `objectTypes` as per https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#class-subsets

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(objectTypes: [MyClass.self, MyOtherClass.self])
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks so much for the rapid response.